# working principle of the ndgrid matlab function

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-c++, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment

I'm trying to migrate an algorithm matlab to c + +.I'm newbie in matlab.
I want to know the working principle of the `ndgrid` matlab function or if there are implementation of this function in c++?

Thank you.

Comment: What would you want as an answer, that can't be found inside the documentation to `ngrid`? Which parts of the function are you having problems with? `ngrid` is implemented as a m-file, you can see the sourcecode using `edit ngrid`.

Comment: Did you ask about How can you convert ngrid function from matlab to C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab can gererate C code for you.

See:
[link](http://www.mathworks.com/products/featured/embeddedmatlab/)

The generated code does however depend on matlab libraries.